# How to retrieve sub array of a json element?

Tags: mongodb

Below is the Employee class

```
public class Employee {

  public List<Department> departments;

  public List<Association> association;

  ....

}
```

The data is successfully inserted after population for the above class.

MongoCollection.insert(entity);

On retrieving Employee object via Jongo. It returns only the Employee and not departments.

```
MongoCollection.findOne("{name: '"+name+"'}").as(Employee.class);
```

sample json file.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("577a32894309be1f540cde3e"),
    "active": false,
    "departments": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("577a32894309be1f540cde3f"),
            "description": "sales",
            "name": "sales"
        }
    ],
    "email": "dinesh.rajul@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "dinesh",
    "lastName": "regjuk",
    "name": "admin",
    "password": "hsCIFfVifdOLG3vOUF7jF3x7bEiRCItm7FPiYAVdMW"
}
```

Could you please help me how to query or get the sub array values ("departments") of the json as well? Currently the list returns null when we say employee.getDeparements()

Thanks

Comment: Is this your own password? In that case, you may want to change it ASAP.

Comment: No. it is a dummy password.